# How to send an array of categories and posts in wordpress functions.php?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I make a request to my custom endpoint function in functions.php :

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'wp/v2', '/homepage/', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'custom',
    ) );
} );
```

And in return I get an array of posts of an author id :

```
function custom( $data ) {
    $posts = get_posts( array(
        'author' => $data['17'],
    ) );
    
    if ( empty( $posts ) ) {
        return null;
    }

    return $posts;
}
```

I want to return all posts and all categories but I get an error :

```
return [$posts , $categories ];
```

How can I get All posts and all categories in a single array inside custom function ?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question exactly, but have you tried iteratively adding them to a collection and then returning that?

Comment: Please provider an example result you want

Comment: @DanielRiera I provided an example and edited the main question

Comment: @RonnieLightweightbabyColeman I edited the original question

Comment: _What_ error? One saying that `$categories` is not defined? Well I don’t see it anywhere else in the code you have shown, so where is it supposed to suddenly come from, in that return statement line?

Comment: You want all categories from post or all category from site?

Comment: @DanielRiera All categories from site and all posts in one array

Comment: @DanielRiera All categories from site and all posts in one array

Comment: @MahdiFaraji check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do all of that like this :

```
function custom( $data ) {
     $posts = get_posts( array(
         'post_type' => 'post'
         'author' => $data['17'],
         'numberposts' => -1
     ) );
        
     $categories = get_categories();
    
     return [$posts, $categories];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok try this

```php
function custom( $data ) {
     $posts = get_posts( array(
         'post_type' => 'post'
         'author' => $data['17'],
         'numberposts' => -1
     ) );
        
     $categories = get_categories();
    
     return [$posts, $categories];
 }
```